# Use resources in Class Library from WebForms app

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application there is one class library project and one website. I created a resource file in a class library and modifier of it is public. I need to use this resource in website layer:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:resourceName, ErrorEmptyName %>"></asp:Label>
```

But an error is shown:

> The resource object with key 'ErrorEmptyName' was not found.

But in code-behind I access this key:

```
Label1.Text = resourceName.ErrorEmptyName;
```

and no error.

I find this page but i can not use:
[Referencing resource files from multiple projects in a solution](http://Referencing%20resource%20files%20from%20multiple%20projects%20in%20a%20solution)

What is wrong? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%# resourceName.ErrorEmptyName %>"></asp:Label>
```

maybe you need to import your namespace.